# Unlocking Burst Shot Ex Skill in MegaMan Zero 3

Tags: mega-man-zero

I've been trying to unlock the Burst Shot Ex Skill for a few days now. On the surface my rank should be good enough. I'm on normal mode, I got an A Ranking, not sure what else to do.

[image: MegaMan Zero 3 Burst Shot Fail]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgIWO.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my memory serves right, the screenshot you included only proves that your rank was A ***after*** you completed the mission.

To obtain an EX Skill from a boss you have to fight that boss ***while being at A/S rank***. In that case the boss will start using their version of the EX Skill as a new attack and when you beat them they will give you the skill.

Therefore, you should check that you rank was high enough when you **entered** the stage and not just when you completed it.